# Reference error: self is not defined when implementing firebase messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my `Nextjs` project I'm trying to implement push notification with `firebase messaging` (my firebase version is 8.10.0), after creating the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in my public folder:

```
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"
);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "***"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: null,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

I now created a [utility] file (that I named `Firebase.js`) where I'll implement helper functions like the request token function.

Here is a code snippet from that file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***"
};

!firebase.apps.length && firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

export const requestForToken = () => {
   // func that generates and returns a FCM token
};

export const onMessageListener = async () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
            resolve(payload);
        }
    );
});
```

Now to use those functions I created another file `Notification.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { requestForToken, onMessageListener } from "./Firebase";

const Notification = () => {
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState({ title: "", body: "" });

    useEffect(() => {
        requestForToken();
    }, []);
  
    const ToastDisplay = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <b>{notification?.title} </b>
                <p>{notification?.body}</p>
            </>
        );
    };

    const notify = () => toast(<ToastDisplay />);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        notification?.title && notify();
    }, [notification]);

    onMessageListener()
        .then((payload) => {
            setNotification({
                title: payload?.notification?.title,
                body: payload?.notification?.body,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("failed: ", err));

    return <></>;
};

export default Notification;
```

I imported `Notification.js` in `_app.js` and when I run my app I get the following error:
[image]

And I can't understand the reason why and [more importantly] how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this should work as All the setup I have worked inclined with your requirement,

Here are version's those I am using,

```
"next": "^12.0.7",
"firebase": "^8.6.8",
"@firebase/installations": "^0.5.4"
```

Here is firebase init'n,

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
// import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import firebaseClient from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/installations";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/messaging";
import "firebase/functions";
import "firebase/analytics";

const CLIENT_CONFIG = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "***",
};
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && firebaseClient.apps?.length <= 0) {
  firebaseClient.initializeApp(CLIENT_CONFIG);

  (window as any).firebase = firebaseClient;
  if (firebaseClient.messaging.isSupported()) {
    const msg = firebaseClient.messaging();
    const creds = {
      vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_WEB_FCM_TOKEN
        ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_WEB_FCM_TOKEN
        : "",
    };
    msg.getToken(
      creds,
    )
      .then((token) => {
        // Send the token to your app server if notification service granted
        console.log(token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // If user blocks notification service
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}

export { firebaseClient };
```

Here is the firebase-messaging-sw.js at `public` folder

```
/* eslint-disable space-before-function-paren */
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("../firebase-messaging-sw.js")
    .then((registration) => {
      console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration.scope);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:", err);
    });
}
```

Hope this get your working!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    // ...
})

// ...
```

Also take a look into firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

EDIT:
Take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) too. It's showing how to receive messages into client.

Hope I've helped you with something :)

Comment: firebase v9 doesn't work with ```Nextjs``` which is why I'm going back to v8

Comment: @Daniel_Kamel Firebase v9 works with NextJS 13, I'm using it at this moment with WIP project. Perhaps you're doing something else wrong in firebase configs/initalization